# iOS 8: UITableViewCell.contentView doesn't resize subviews in it

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout

I put an `CustomView` in `UITableViewCell.contentView`, setting the `autoresize mask` of the custom view as `W+H`.

But when running, the `CustomView` gets a larger height than the `ContentView`, the `ContentView` is `60pt` in height(which is the same as setting in `UITableViewDelegate`), but the `CustomView` inside `contentView` is `76pt` in height.

By `Xcode6's view debugging`, I see some strange constraints on my custom view, they are:

```
self.height = superview.height + 16

self.midY = superview.midY + 8
```

Where are these constraints come from and how to modify them? I've never set anything with a value 8 or 16.

**UPDATE:**

I've made a test project, which is simply a tableview in storyboard with a `CustomView` loaded from a nib file, and this test project replicated the problem, when running, the `CustomView` which is a subview of `TableViewCell.contentView` becomes larger in height than the `TableViewCell.contentView`.

The test project is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5y_NrRbhGlSb1dlbVZNb19vNjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: have you disabled autolayout from IB in storyboard.

Comment: @AshishP. whose auto layout? tableview or CustomView?

Comment: it belongs to your entire storyboard. try to uncheck it and then check.

Comment: @AshishP. the CustomView is not in the storyboard of the table view, it is in a xib file, which is loaded dynamically.

Comment: Ok. So you are using autolayout in storyboard and you are loading your custom view from xib file. Then just try to add constraints on your custom view with respect to parent view programmatically. This might help to keep custom views height within contentview boundary.

Comment: @AshishP. please see my test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I understand, auto layout can only form relations in the same xib or storyboard, my CustomView is in a separated xib and is loaded at runtime, so the super view and CustomView don't have any auto layout constraints between them.

If I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to YES, then there goes the problem, I still don't know why using W+H as auto resizing mask makes CustomView taller than its super view(cell.contentView), but I found a way around:

I manually add constraints between superview and CustomView, and turn off `customView. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, there the code goes:

```
    customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *left = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *right = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0];

    [cell.contentView addConstraints:@[top, bottom, left, right]];
```